# IEnumerable<> data loss in HttpPost when part of a Complex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Suppose I have this View Model:

```
public class CreateGameViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SideA { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SideB { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public IEnumerable<int> ConfigurableCategoryIDs { get; set; }
}
```

And these Actions:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new CreateGameViewModel { ConfigurableCategoryIDs = new List { 1, 1, 1 } };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateGameViewModel viewModel)
    {
    ...
    }
```

And in the View I try to edit ConfigurableCategoryIDs values:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs.ElementAt(@i);
        @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
    }
```

**CreateGameViewModel.ConfigurableCategoryIDs** is returned to Create(CreateGameViewModel viewModel) as null while SideA and SideB has values.

Would be grateful for an explanation and solution!
Thanks

Comment: Why are you looping in your view? `@Html.EditorFor` will work for collections.

Comment: Even with this:
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs)

The returned CreateGameViewModel.ConfigurableCategoryIDs to Create(CreateGameViewModel viewModel) is EMPTY (count = 0)!

Comment: What's the editor template look like?

Comment: The default.
All I want is to receive this list back to my HttpPost Action with the values passed to the View in the HttpGet. (the EditorFor makes it be added to Form collection of the request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try next:

Model:

```
public class CreateGameViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SideA { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SideB { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public List<int> ConfigurableCategoryIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new CreateGameViewModel { ConfigurableCategoryIDs = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1 } };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateGameViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CreateGameViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>CreateGameViewModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SideA)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SideA)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SideA)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SideB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SideB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SideB)
    </div>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs[i])
    }

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: That brings an exception:

Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Source Error:
Line 42: @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs[@i])

Comment: Oh yes. Is it ok to change public IEnumerable<int> ConfigurableCategoryIDs { get; set; } to List<int> ConfigurableCategoryIDs { get; set; }? If yes please change.

Comment: Same same. Actually it is not null. but Count = 0 when it is returned.

Comment: I have just tried it in VS. It works for me. Could you please provide html code of inputs generated for ConfigurableCategoryIds?

Comment: <input id="ConfigurableCategoryIDs" name="ConfigurableCategoryIDs" type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" />

Comment: and the returned list is with Count = 0.

Comment: It seems you have done something incorrect. Please make sure that you have written indexer at the end @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs[i])
and NOT @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs). HTML code generated should look like this for each input: <input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="ConfigurableCategoryIDs_1_" name="ConfigurableCategoryIDs[1]" type="text" value="1">

Comment: Ok my bad! you are right.
But still when it returns to the HttpPost action Create(CreateGameViewModel viewModel) , it returned as an empty list!!

Comment: I will update my answer and include all code. Please copy paste it and try. It works for me.

Comment: When your HttpPost action received the request, was it a non empty list? (was your list part of a complex???).
Anyway, I am waiting! thanks.

Comment: Please find code in answer. Yes list contains data I have entered (3 entries for now).

Comment: It works! thanks.
But any idea why it doesn't work for IEnumerable? so weird to me.

Comment: Maybe because the DefaultBinder will try to instantiate the static type (IEnumerable) and it doesn't know about the dynamic one, thus fails to?

Comment: Default MVC binder need index in input names rendered so it can know which element of collection it is. If you don't specify index all names will be the same and MVC doesn't know how to bind elements of collection. Please read this article for more details http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx. And also it would be cool if you accept my answer :)

Comment: Actually, I see the values in:
Request.Form["Item"] = "1,1,1"

How come it failed to insert them to list ? (static type here is IEnumerable!!! dynamic is List<int>)

Comment: This will make it work:
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = Model.ConfigurableCategoryIDs.ElementAt(i);
        @Html.Hidden("ConfigurableCategoryIDs"+"["+i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)+"]", item)
    }

Comment: Yes if you want to go with IEnumerable it will. The case is MVC binder neesd indexes [i] in request to know that it is array/collection. "1, 1, 1" is comma separated string. MVC doesn't recognizes it as array.